# O que é primeiro plano e segundo plano no Android?

Tags: android, terminologia

Gostaria de saber o que significa primeiro ou segundo plano no Android.

Answer (score 6):

São 2 de 5 níveis de importância que o Android usa para classificar um processo.
Para determinar quais processos manter e quais terminar, o sistema atribui, a cada um, um nível de importância com base nos componentes em execução e no estado deles.

O Android define os seguintes níveis de importância:

1. **Primeiro plano.** - Processo necessário para o que o usuário está fazendo.
2. **Visível** - Processo que não tem nenhum componente em primeiro plano, mas que ainda possa afectar o que o usuário vê na tela.
3. **Serviço** - Processos que executem um serviço que tenha sido iniciado com o método `startService()` e não esteja em uma das duas categorias mais altas.
4. **Segundo plano** - Processo que mantém uma actividade que não esteja actualmente visível para o usuário.
5. **Vazio** - Processo que não tem nenhum componente de aplicativo activo.

Noutro contexto, "segundo plano"(*background*) pode referir-se à execução de código em uma thread(*worker thread*) que não a thread principal(*main thread*).

Para informação mais completa veja, na documentação, o guia [Processos e encadeamentos.](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html?hl=pt-br)

Answer (score 5):

**Resumo**

De maneira geral, o App em **primeiro plano** é aquele você vê aberto na tela do celular. Todo e qualquer tipo de ação/função em primeiro plano é finalizado quando você fecha o App.

Já em **segundo plano** ficam aquelas execuções do App que não tem uma interface visual. Alguns continuam funcionando até mesmo após fechar o App.

**Explicação detalhada**

Por exemplo quando você recebe uma notificação, ela é mostrada na barra de *status*. Existe um serviço no qual permanece em execução que é responsável pela notificação, mesmo com sua aplicação fechada.

Quando a aplicação está rodando em segundo plano, digamos assim, ele está rodando em *background*, no qual existe um serviço responsável por deixar a aplicação neste modo. Um [Serviço ou Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) é um componente da aplicação que pode executar operações em segundo plano e não fornece uma interface com o usuário. Um outro componente da aplicação pode iniciar um serviço e ele continuará a ser executado em segundo plano mesmo se o usuário passar a usar outra aplicação.